# MySQL' INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Primary Key Limit

Tags: mysql, database

I have a database table on which I am using `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`, where the unique check has been applied on a non-primary key field.

Initially I did not notice, but as the database has grown and has almost 500k records, I notice that the primary key value has gone too high.

Currently I have 507 811 records in the table, but the highest primary key right now is: 4 841 123, which is way higher than it should be.

As quoted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3747340/1339012):

> "INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE works similarly to REPLACE in
>   that when a row with an existing (duplicate) key is found, it's
>   actually removed (1 row affected) and then a new row created in its
>   place (1 more row affected), giving the illusion of updating/replacing
>   a row.",

so should I really use primary key field, because eventually it will go out range one day as the data keeps increasing.

I know it is not a bug, but I really need some more knowledge into this. I have been searching a lot about this. And I realise, either I should just keep the column and remove primary key check and auto-increment from it or increase the size for the column, currently it is int(11).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well that answer you have referred to is plain wrong. This is what the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) says:

> If you specify ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, and a row is inserted that
>   would cause a duplicate value in a UNIQUE index or PRIMARY KEY, MySQL
>   performs an UPDATE of the old row. For example, if column a is
>   declared as UNIQUE and contains the value 1, the following two
>   statements have similar effect:

It clearly says that the row is updated and not replaced. A row is replaced only if you use the `REPLACE INTO` syntax which is a mysql extension.

What's actually happening in your table is the common 'gaps in sequences' problem which is not really a problem at all. This occurs when you delete a row in your table that had say id=100. You might expect a new row with a fresh insert to have id=100 but it will have 101. This in practice is never a problem.

The maximum value that can be [stored](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/integer-types.html) in an int field is 2147483647 and you are a long way from hitting that limit. You can fill roughly 250 times as much data in that table as you have at the moment.